# how to Display Tuple{Float64, Bool}

Tags: julia

I would like that boolean part of Tuple are displayed as such (and not an Integer or a Float) when part of a Matrix.
Here the code:

```
a = [(1., true) (1.5 , true) ; (1.5 , false) (-5.5 , false) ]
2×2 Matrix{Tuple{Float64, Bool}}:
 (1.0, 1)  (1.5, 1)
 (1.5, 0)  (-5.5, 0)
```

However I was hoping for the following result:

```
2×2 Matrix{Tuple{Float64, Bool}}:
 (1.0, true)  (1.5, true)
 (1.5, false)  (-5.5, false)
```

I guess I am missing something in Julia's type; any help is appreciated.

By accident I realized that:

```
b = [(1., true) (1.5 , true) ; (false, 1.5) (false, -5.5) ]
2×2 Matrix{Tuple{Real, Real}}:
 (1.0, true)   (1.5, true)
 (false, 1.5)  (false, -5.5)
```

Display the Boolean as I would have expected for a (the first case). It is also unexpected that the Booleans are displayed as such when the Tuple's type is `Tuple{Real, Real}`. Again I feel that I am missing something; any pointer to a specific part of the documentation is welcomed.
I am using Julia 1.6.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Julia shows Bool type values in arrays like 0 and 1, making displaying more compact. And that is done for compatibility with bit array (which saves boolean values in one bit). e.g.:

```
julia> [true, false]
2-element Vector{Bool}:
 1
 0
```

Since we know the type of the array's elements is Bool, we understand that `1` is a `true`, and `0` is `false`.

But `0` or `1` is used when that is obvious from the type that those are boolean values. For your first case, tuple of float and boolean, and that was obvious that `1` is for `true` and `0` for `false`.

When creating arrays from values, Julia uses a common type for all values, which is `Real`. But for the second case that would not be clear: 1 is true, or 1 is an integer one. That is why Julia displays `true` and `false` for the second case.

If you want to use a type that could contain `Bool` or `Float64` only, you can do it explicitly with Union{Float64, Bool}.

Thus if you want to show `true` or `false`, you could explicitly set Union type:

```
julia> a = Tuple{Union{Float64, Bool}, Union{Float64, Bool}}[(1., true) (1.5 , true) ; (1.5 , false) (-5.5 , false) ]
2×2 Matrix{Tuple{Union{Bool, Float64}, Union{Bool, Float64}}}:
 (1.0, true)   (1.5, true)
 (1.5, false)  (-5.5, false)
```

**Update:** This example only for the sake of explanation. If the second element in your tuple supposed to contain only `Bool` values, changing its type to `Union{Float64,Bool}` may dramatically affect performance.

Comment: This changes the type of the data in `a`

Comment: Yes but AFAIK there is no other way for the case (except overload the default display method, which is a “piracy”)

Comment: Interesting, thank you for providing the explanation. Did you figure it out by looking into the display method?

Comment: I cannot find the documentation that explains that, but I remember older versions of Julia worked differently. It used to print [true, false] as [true, false] but not as [1,0].  If you need nice table printing abilities, you may take a look at packages like https://github.com/ronisbr/PrettyTables.jl or https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl